# Vuetify Sidebar jumping on mobile

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, sidebar

website is:
app.superiorprediction.com

Please check orange sidebar on mobile version.
When scrolling bottom on mobile browsers, its navbar and footer appear and disappear and this causes ugly stuck of my sidebar while holding the scroll with finger on mobile.
Is there any fix for this or should i look for more elegant solutions and if so what are they?
Here's the code of Sidebar component

```
<template>

  <v-main style="overflow: hidden; !important; ">

    <v-navigation-drawer
        app
        permanent
        style=" z-index: 5;"
        height="100%"
        :width="check"
        v-bind:style="miniFied ? 'v-navigation-drawer--mini-variant {overflow: hidden;} ' : null"
        :mini-variant="miniFied"
        class="pt-14 amber darken-1"
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-btn
            icon
            @click.stop="miniFied = !miniFied"
        >
          <v-icon v-if="!miniFied">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
          <v-icon v-else>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-list-item class="px-2" v-if="!miniFied">

          <v-img :src="require('@/assets/logo.webp')"
                 max-height="80"
                 max-width="70"
                 class="mx-auto">

          </v-img>

        </v-list-item>
        <v-container v-if="user.nameSurname" class="pa-0 ma-0">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-if="!miniFied" style="font-size: 20px" class="text-center">
                {{ user.nameSurname }}
              </v-list-item-title>

              <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-center" v-if="!mini">{{ user.email }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-container>

        <v-container v-else class="pa-0">
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-if="!miniFied" class="text-h6 text-center">
                <v-btn :to="{ path: '/register' }" dark>
                  Register
                </v-btn>
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-container>
        <v-container class="pa-0 ma-0">
        <v-list-item v-if="user.ipCount && user.role === 'ADMIN' || user.role === 'SUPER_ADMIN' && !miniFied"
        class="ma-0 pa-0">
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item class="justify-center pa-0"
                          >
              <span class="text-center text-subtitle-2">Total Unique IPs: {{ user.ipCount }}</span>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        </v-container>
      </v-list>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list
          nav
          dense
      >
        <v-list-item-group
            light
            class="pb-16 text-left"
            :value="selected"
            color="primary"
        >

          <v-list-item link @click="clickedMenuItem('superior-predictions')" :disabled="selectedItem === 0">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Dashboard</v-list-item-title>

          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link @click="clickedMenuItem('history')" :disabled="selectedItem === 1">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-history</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Prediction History</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link @click="clickedMenuItem('bank')" :disabled="selectedItem === 2">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-bank</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Virtual Bank</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item link @click="clickedMenuItem('charts')" :disabled="selectedItem === 3">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-chart-bell-curve-cumulative</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Charts</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link
                       href="https://superiorprediction.com/blog"
                       target="_blank">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-newspaper-variant-outline</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Blog - Latest News</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item v-if="loggedIn" link @click="clickedMenuItem('profile')" :disabled="selectedItem === 4">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">My Profile</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item v-if="user.role === 'ADMIN' || user.role === 'SUPER_ADMIN'" link
                       @click="clickedMenuItem('admin-panel')" :disabled="selectedItem === 5">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-solar-panel</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px">Admin Panel</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
      <template v-slot:append style="height: 100% !important;">
        <div class="pb-5">


          <v-dialog
              transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
              max-width="600"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">

              <v-list-item link v-bind="attrs"
                           v-on="on"
              >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon color="blue darken-3">mdi-send</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px" class="text-left">Join Telegram</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>

            </template>
            <template v-slot:default="dialog">
              <v-card>

                <v-card-text class="pa-10 text-center">
                  <v-img :src="require('@/assets/telegram.webp')"
                         max-height="200"
                         max-width="200"
                         class="mx-auto"
                  ></v-img>
                  <span class="text-h6 ">Get free predictions now!</span>
                  <v-card-text>
                    <v-btn color="primary" class="btn btn-info text-white "
                           href="https://t.me/+nHbAu6aUFLsxZjY0" target="_blank">
                      Join
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card-text>


                <v-card-actions class="justify-end">

                  <v-btn
                      color="amber darken-1"
                      @click="dialog.value = false"
                  >Close
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </template>
          </v-dialog>

          <v-dialog
              transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
              max-width="600"

          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">

              <v-list-item link v-bind="attrs"
                           v-on="on">
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon color="black">mdi-gift</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px" class="text-left">Donate Paypal</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>

            </template>
            <template v-slot:default="dialog">
              <v-card>
                <v-img :src="require('@/assets/paypal.webp')"
                       max-height="140"
                       max-width="340"
                       class="mx-auto text-left"
                >
                </v-img>
                <v-card-text class="pa-7 text-center">
                  <v-btn color="primary" href="https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/superiorprediction">Donate Link
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn
                      color="amber darken-1"
                      @click="dialog.value = false"
                  >Close
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </template>
          </v-dialog>



          <v-dialog
              transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
              max-width="600"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">

              <v-list-item link v-bind="attrs"
                           v-on="on">
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon color="grey darken-4">mdi-gift</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-title style="font-size: 17px" class="text-left">Donate BTC</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>

            </template>
            <template v-slot:default="dialog">
              <v-card>
                <v-img :src="require('@/assets/frame.png')"
                       max-height="200"
                       max-width="200"
                       class="mx-auto pa-0"
                >
                </v-img>
                <v-card-text class="pb-5 text-center">
                  <span class="text-h6 ">Donate BTC Address: {{ donateAddress }}</span>

                  <input type="hidden" id="donate-address" :value="donateAddress">
                </v-card-text>

                <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
                  <v-btn color="primary" class="btn btn-info text-white copy-btn "
                         @click.stop.prevent="copyTestingCode">
                    Copy
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn
                      color="amber darken-1"
                      @click="dialog.value = false"
                  >Close
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </template>
          </v-dialog>
        </div>
      </template>

    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the height of your v-navigation-drawer in the props. The reason is it is doing so is because the default is 100%, so the drawer will resize when you scroll.

Try

```
<v-navigation-drawer
        app
        height="100vh"
        permanent
        style=" z-index: 5;"
        height="100%"
        :width="check"
        v-bind:style="miniFied ? 'v-navigation-drawer--mini-variant {overflow: hidden;} ' : null"
        :mini-variant="miniFied"
        class="pt-14 amber darken-1"
    >
```

Comment: It doesn't work.